# Intent not working with if operator Android

Tags: java, android

I try when it displays a message when I press a button to redirect me to a page, but it doesn't work. When successful, the message is displayed but does not forward me.

```
private void registerUser() {
    try {

        Account account = new Account();
        account.setpAddress(edt_adress.getText().toString());
        account.setpBloodGroup(edt_blood.getSelectedItem().toString());
        account.setpFirstName(edt_first.getText().toString());
        account.setpMidName(edt_mid.getText().toString());
        account.setpFamilyName(edt_fam.getText().toString());
        account.setpGender(edt_gender.getSelectedItem().toString());
        account.setpPhone(edt_phone.getText().toString());
        account.setpEgn(edt_egn.getText().toString());
        account.setuPassword(edt_password.getText().toString());
        account.setuUsername(edt_username.getText().toString());
        INodeJS accountservice = RetrofitClient.getInstance().create(INodeJS.class);
        Call call = accountservice.create(account);
        call.enqueue(new Callback() {
            @Override
            public void onResponse(Call call, Response response) {
                Account result = (Account) response.body();
                
                Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), result.getNotes(), Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
                if (result.getNotes().equals("Success")) {
                    Intent intent = new Intent(LoginActivity.this, MainActivity.class);
                    startActivity(intent);
                }
                // startActivity(intent);
            }



            @Override
            public void onFailure(Call call, Throwable t) {
                Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), getString(R.string.createfield), Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
            }
        });

    } catch (Exception e) {
        Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), e.getMessage(), Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
    }
}
```

Comment: well, is `if (result.getNotes().equals("Success")) {` this true ? your toast is inside `onResponse` and not inside the `if`

Answer (score 0):

looks like `result.getNotes().equals("Success")` isnt true, are you shure it should be? `equals` is case-sensitive so "success" doesn't equal "Success" and also " Success " - note whitespaces

maybe you can try with this statement:

```
result.getNotes().toLowerCase(Locale.getDefault()).trim().equals("success")
```

`toLowerCase` will make all your letters small caps and `trim` will remove all whitespaces at beggining and end of `String`

also there is `equalsIgnoreCase` method so it may also looks like below:

```
result.getNotes().trim().equalsIgnoreCase("success")
```

Comment: The text is spelled correctly. He tries your example, but it still doesn't work